# Downloading the expansion packs and the DLCs

Tags: xbox-one, the-witcher-3

I have three questions for you:

1. I play on Xbox One and already have a The Witcher 3 hard copy. Can I just buy the expansion pass (containing B&W and HoS), install it and continue my already existing saved games?
2. Does the expansion pass also include in itself the 16 small dlcs or do you have to download them yourself?
3. What's the preferred method of buying the expansion packs? (Amazon/Microsoft store/from inside the game)

Comment: 1. That's 3 questions and 2. Please limit yourself to one question per question...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first two questions:

1. Yes, you can do this. I personally activated my Season Pass after purchasing (and beating the game) and it worked just fine.
2. No, the expansion pass does not include any of the DLCs in it. It includes the *license* to the DLCs. Thus, you have to download them manually. The same goes for the other 16 DLCs (not sure if that's the right number). Those are free DLCs, for the record, mostly containing new armors or weapons, if I recall correctly.

I cannot answer the third question as that is entirely opinion-based. My recommendation would be to buy from whichever vendor is selling for the cheapest price at the time (look for sales).